# Rotate PDF in UIWebView with Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, pdf, uiwebview

I got a view that is used to show different PDF files in a `UIWebView`, this `UIWebView` load the PDF file as `NSData` like:

```
webView.loadData(pdfData, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: NSURL())
```

Now there are some PDF files that need to be rotated via `UIButton`  that is above the `UIWebView`, is there a way to rotate the PDF inside of the `UIWebView`?

What i did try so far was

`webView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2)`)

but this was not getting me the result i was looking for.

Comment: I would like to answer this question but before that please provide me answers of following:- 1. Do you want to update the frame of web view only or rotate the screen orientation for that particular pdf. 2. Are you using auto layouts.

Comment: @pkc456 yes i do use auto layout, i simply want to "turn the pdf" aka the webview content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- To rotate the single view-controller in application, override the `shouldAutorotate` method.
- Check the current `statusBarOrientation`, then update the `UIInterfaceOrientation` as follows:-

  ```
  let interfaceOrienation : UIInterfaceOrientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation

  if(interfaceOrienation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait){
      let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
      UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
  }else{
      let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
      UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
  }
  ```

I developed a `sample project` for you. Please follow the below link to download the `full code`.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3hk5y9g7v74cbkd/Stackoverflow_webview.zip?dl=0

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot @pkc456, but this turns the complete screen so also the "titlebar" get turned :-/ same for my overlay buttons on top of the webview, i was thinking about a way to just return the "webview"

Answer (score 3):

If I have understand your problem it's to center your PDF after you have rotate it, to showing it correctly from the top, unfortunately `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` only it's not enough..

You can do:

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = true
let scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.6)
let translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(webView.frame.origin.x, webView.frame.origin.y - webView.frame.size.height * 0.25)
let transform =  CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);
webView.transform =  CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```

And to return back from transform:

```
webView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
```

There is also another working method but **I don't recommend to do**:

(it's too long and too hard to handle html page just to make a rotation..)

*set webView* -> *load a responsive HTML page* -> *this responsive HTML page load PDF* -> *inject to webView the following javascript code*

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    let js = "document.body.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(-90deg)', null);"
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(js)
}
```

You can check your JS also from [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/vvWUt/) if you want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently i do use this code to rotate, but the "view does not stay centered (i think based on my auto layout)

```
print(webView.transform)
        if (webView.transform.a == 1.0 && webView.transform.d == 1.0) {webView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI/2));print("done1")}
        else if(webView.transform.b == 1.0 && webView.transform.c == -1.0) {webView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI));print("done2")}
        else if(webView.transform.a == -1.0 && webView.transform.d == -1.0) {webView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI+(M_PI/2)));print("done3")}
        else if(webView.transform.b == -1.0 && webView.transform.c == 1.0) {webView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI + M_PI));print("done4")}
        else{print("nothing happens")}
```

example vid
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iCuD.jpg

Comment: Replace M_PI with Double.pi for avoid type casting